# Finding a matrix with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: R^2 \to R^2$ be represented by $\begin{bmatrix}5 & -3\\2 & -2\end{bmatrix}$ with respect to the standard basis. Find the matrix T with respect to the basis B = { $\begin{bmatrix}3 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ , $\begin{bmatrix}1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$ }.

I found T$\begin{bmatrix}3 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ and T$\begin{bmatrix}1\\2 \end{bmatrix}$ by:

$\begin{bmatrix}5 & -3\\2 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}3 \\1\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}12 \\4\end{bmatrix}$ and

$\begin{bmatrix}5 & -3\\2 & -2\end{bmatrix}$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2\end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\-2\end{bmatrix}$

so that $[T]_B$ = $\begin{bmatrix}12 & -1\\4 & -2\end{bmatrix}$

but I'm not sure if this is correct. Am I doing the right thing or are my steps wrong?

Comment: No, this answer is not right. The columns of $[T]_B$ should not be $T\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\end{pmatrix}$ and $T\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ themselves, but rather the _coordinate vectors_ of these relative to the basis $B$.

Comment: The answer is incorrect.

Comment: Ok so I need to write [12,4] = a[3,1] + b[1,2] and then the first column of $[T]_B$ would be [a,b]?

Comment: @user127273, yes, that would work.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: I have assumed that the basis was changed in both the domain and the range in this answer.

If $y$ is a point expressed in the new basis, then it corresponds to a point  $x=By$ in the old basis.

So, to compute the new form of the operator $T$, first map from the new coordinates to the old (multiply by $B$), then perform the mapping to get the mapped point in the old coordinates (multiply by $T$) and then map into the new coordinates (multiply by $B^{-1}$).

Putting these together gives $\tilde{T} = B^{-1} T B$.

Note that in this particular example, $T$ behaves as multiplication on the rows of $B$ (that is, $B$ is a matrix of eigenvectors), this should help considerably with the computations. In fact, if you think carefully, little computation will be needed (other than multiplying the columns of $B$ by $T$)...

Note that $B^{-1} T B = \operatorname{diag} (4, -1)$.

Comment: I like your explanation, but I came across this lecture: https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m24w07/public_html/Lecture12.pdf . One page 5, it seems they are doing what the OP did. That is, to calculate T wrt to new basis $B$, they just did $T*B$. Isn't this wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: If the basis is only changed for the domain then this is correct. I presumed the basis was changed in both the domain and range.

Comment: "If the basis is only changed for the domain then this is correct" ... does the "this" refer to your solution or to the work referred to by the link?

Comment: My solution presumed the basis was changed in both the domain and range, the solution in the link only changes the domain basis.

Comment: In the link that you gave out. We are changing the basis of $R^3$ which is the domain of the linear transformation. We are not changing the basis of $A$, the representation of the linear transformation as a matrix. Watch out for that, and read the question carefully!. In your question, If basis of the $R^2$ was changed, than your answer would have been correct. But we are asked to changed to basis of the transformation matrix.

Comment: What link are you referring to?