# Finding Basis Transformation Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $A=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}$ be a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ by the elementary basis $B$ and let $V=\{(1 ,0 ,0),(1 ,1 ,0),(0 ,0 ,1)\}$ basis such that the $A$ is diagonal.

I am trying to show that $[I]^{B}_{V}[T]_{B}=[T]_V$

So we have to solve

$(1,0,0)=\alpha(1 ,0 ,0)+\beta(1 ,1 ,0)+\gamma(0 ,0 ,1)$

$(0,1,0)=\alpha(1 ,0 ,0)+\beta(1 ,1 ,0)+\gamma(0 ,0 ,1)$

$(0,01,1)=\alpha(1 ,0 ,0)+\beta(1 ,1 ,0)+\gamma(0 ,0 ,1)$

which is $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ but $\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 
\end{pmatrix}\neq \text{diagonal}$

Comment: For a base change you have to compute $SAS^{-1}$ and not $A^2$.

Comment: So $S=[I]^B_V$ and $S^{-1}=[I]_{B}^V$?

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676566/finding-a-matrix-with-respect-to-a-basis), how it works.

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\, $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$S=
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

then by the change of basis $y=Sv$ and $x=Su$, we have that

$$y=Ax \implies Sv=ASu \implies v=S^{-1}ASu$$