# what is Matrix of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I am a student and I'm studying linear algebra. in the Sheldon Axler book in the part "The Spectral Theorem" and in [this video](http://The%20Spectral%20Theorem) he mentions the operator $T$ as
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}2&-3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}$$

then after finding it's eigenvectors $2 + 3i$ and $2 - 3i$ (in the video I've linked), he says: "with respect to this basis, the matrix of $T$ is the diagonal matrix":
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 2 + 3i&0 \\ 
 0&2 - 3i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am confused. $T$ already mentions as $T=\begin{pmatrix}2&-3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}$ so the matrix of $T$ must be $\begin{pmatrix}2&-3\\3&2\end{pmatrix}$ so I think that I don't know the meaning of the **matrix of $T$**.

could you help me figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices only define linear transformations relative to some basis. They don't describe a linear transformation on their own. Thus implicit in $$T=\begin{pmatrix} 2&-3 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
is the statement that the vector space has some basis already and that this is the matrix for $T$ *with respect to that basis*. E.g., perhaps it's $k^2$, so it has the standard basis vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ already, and $T$ has that matrix with respect to that basis.

If $V$ is a vector space, then a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ is not a matrix, but rather a function with nice properties that respect the vector space structure. We can then describe it using bases and a matrix, but that's only a description, and the description depends on the basis used to compute the matrix.

As for how to compute the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to some basis, look [here](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH304-503/Lect2-12web.pdf) for some random notes I found online, or in any decent linear algebra textbook, like presumably in Axler's book somewhere (It [appears](http://linear.axler.net/Contents.pdf) to be section 3C). For an example of how to do this in a particular case, you can look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/676566/90543).

Comment: great answer, thanks.

Comment: @Peyman Glad it was helpful, also the matrix for a linear transformation appears to be defined in section 3C of Axler's book based on a table of contents I found online.